# Adding multiple custom fields to WooCommerce customer note

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I need to retrieve 3 custom fields from a delivery plugin and put their values in the same woocommerce private note. I'm using this code, it works for the first custom field `delivery_date`  but not for the others (I tried `false` at the end):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'add_engraving_notes' );
function add_engraving_notes( $order_id ) {

//because I already have the ID from the hook I am using.
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// The text for the note
$note = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'delivery_date', 'time_slot_from', 'time_slot_to', true );

// Add the note
$order->add_order_note( $note );

// Save the data
$order->save();
}
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'add_engraving_notes' );

function add_engraving_notes( $order_id ) {

//because I already have the ID from the hook I am using.
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// The text for the note
    $delivery_date   = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'delivery_date', true );
    $time_slot_from  = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'time_slot_from', true );
    $time_slot_to    = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'time_slot_to', true );

    $note = "Deliver Date:$delivery_date Time Slot From: $time_slot_from Time Slot To: $time_slot_to";

// Add the note
    $order->add_order_note( $note );

// Save the data
    $order->save();
}
```

Try this

Comment: @nemovich Glad that it helped

Comment: how about saving to customer note? could you help too?